# Dividend Dynamics under Q Measure / Using Girsanov Theorem with Covariance

Tags: brownian-motion, risk-neutral-measure

I want to find the value of a dividend stream. I can do it under the P-measure, but now I would also like to do it under the Q-measure but cant figure out how to derive the dynamics of the dividend under Q.

I have the dynamics of the dividend stream and the stochastic discount factor with two dependent Brownian motions :

$$
dD_t=D_t[\alpha dt + \beta dW_t]
$$
$$
dH_t=-H_t[r dt + \theta dB_t]
$$

where $ \theta$  is the market price of risk and the instantaneous covariance is $ <W_t,B_t>=\rho$.

I want to calculate the value of the dividend stream ($V_t$). Under the P-measure I arrive at:

$$
V_t=E^P[\int_{t}^{T}H_t D_t ds] = \frac{1}{\alpha -r-\rho \beta \theta} D_t [exp[(T-t)(\alpha-r-\rho \beta \theta)] - 1]
$$
(Which I think is correct. I happily provide more steps if asked for)

Now I want to calculate the same under the Q-measure:
$$
V_t=E^Q[\int_{t}^{T} exp(-r) D_t ds]
$$

The result should obviously be the same, but I cant figure out how to derive the dynamics of $D_t$ under the risk-neutral measure: $$ dD_t = D_t[\alpha^Q dt + \beta^Q dW_{t}^{Q}] $$ , where $\alpha^Q$ and $\beta^Q$ are placeholders.

I think the solution should be: $ dD_t = D_t[(\alpha-\rho \beta \theta) dt + \beta dW_{t}^{Q}] $, since this would lead to the same result as under P, but I don't see how to get there. So far I never used Girsanovs Theorem in a case where covariance was involved, so I don't understand where $\rho$ comes from.